# How to Get Set Linq Entity With Only String Name

Tags: string, linq, linq-to-sql, entity, datacontext

Okay so I have the string name of the linq entity.

```
string table = "Person";
```

I have the datacontext and there's an entity or database table called Person.

I'd like to be about to somehow using the string of the table name create a new Person entity and set all the attributes.

I really don't have much code for this example but let me try and write something.

```
MetaTable table = SetTable(); //Gets the metatable of the entity
string tableName = table.TableName; //"Person"
//Stuck there
//...
//What I'd like to do
//Somehow get Person then
Person p = new Person();
p.Name = "Joe";
db.Person.InsertOnSubmit(p);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, it's absolutely unclear what you're at. What does `SetTable` do? What is "the entity" in line 1? What is the greater picture here?

Comment: The first line get the Person table name via Meta data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This way to get data

```
AdventureWorksDataContext dataContext = 
            new AdventureWorksDataContext();

        var query = from contact in dataContext.Contacts
                  select contact;
```

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't really help at all. I'm not trying to query anything. I'm trying to set the Person object values. The problem is this has to be done dynamically and I only have the string name of the Person (object/table) instance.